# How can we change ['1', '2', '3', '4'] for [1, 2, 3, 4]?

Tags: python

i'm trying to plot .csv data (DataFrame) but there are some conversion problems.
How can we change ['1', '2', '3', '4'] for [1, 2, 3, 4] ?

```
data =         nbColonnes  nbPoints     start       pas  Unnamed: 4
0               1   10000.0  0,000000  0,001000         NaN
1      298,444122       NaN       NaN       NaN         NaN
2      298,953156       NaN       NaN       NaN         NaN
3      299,710266       NaN       NaN       NaN         NaN
4      298,416321       NaN       NaN       NaN         NaN
          ...       ...       ...       ...         ...
9996   298,482086       NaN       NaN       NaN         NaN
9997   298,537598       NaN       NaN       NaN         NaN
9998   303,637482       NaN       NaN       NaN         NaN
9999   304,119171       NaN       NaN       NaN         NaN
10000  298,549774       NaN       NaN       NaN         NaN
```

Comment: Use a list conversion, `[int(i) for i in list]` will change all those strings to ints.

Comment: Where's `['1', '2', '3', '4']` in your data?

Comment: Look into the documentation for pandas [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), especially into the parameters `dtype`